# Jquery change image randomly on click

Tags: jquery, html

Html

```
    <body>
        <img class = die src="one.jpg">
        <img class = die src="two.jpg">
        <img class = die src="three.jpg">
        <img class = die src="energy.jpg">
        <img class = die src="hit.jpg">
        <img class = die src="heal.jpg">
    </body>
```

Jquery

```
 var dice = ["one.jpg","two.jpg","three.jpg","energy.jpg","hit.jpg","heal.jpg"];
    $(function() {
        $('.die').click(function() {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*dice.length);
            $(this).html('<img src="'+dice[num]+'">');
        });
    });
```

Whenever I test it out it would not change the image 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the src attribute of the `img` which was clicked

```js
$(function() {
  //var dice = ["//placehold.it/64X64&text=1", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=2", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=3", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=4", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=5", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=6"];

  //create the array dynamically using the .die elements
  var dice = $('.die').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
  }).get();

  $('.die').click(function() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length);
    //This may not change the image always as the same src can be selected by this logic
    $(this).attr('src', dice[num]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=3">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=4">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=5">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=6">
```

The `die` element is an `img` element, you can't set the `innerHTML` of `img` element, instead you need to change the `src` attribute to change the image

---

If you want to change the image in every click

```js
$(function() {
  //var dice = ["//placehold.it/64X64&text=1", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=2", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=3", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=4", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=5", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=6"];

  //create the array dynamically using the .die elements
  var dice = $('.die').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
  }).get();

  $('.die').click(function() {
    var src, curr = $(this).attr('src');
    do {
      src = dice[Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length)]
    } while (src == curr);
    $(this).attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=3">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=4">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=5">
<img class="die" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=6">
```